# How inner anonymous function have scope of outer function?

Tags: javascript

In the script shown below

```
$(function(){
    var outerValue="OuterValue";
    $('#btnScope').click(function(){
        alert(outerValue);
    });
});
```

The outer function (ie `$()`) executes when the page loads. At this time click event will be bound to anonymous function (which alerts). This function uses value of `outerValue` which might have lost scope after completing the ready(`$()`) function. How this is possible? How could I know the scope of variable?

How the interpreter define its scope?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The outer scope is not *lost*. The scoping as you describe it is fairly accurate.

A variable's scope is roughly where it's defined (where `var` is). Any inner scope can access anything in it's outer scope. Only functions have scope though; not `if`, `for`, `while` or `switch`.

Comment: That means the variable should keep the value always. How then its garbage collected? If I didn't used the variable inside another function would it had lost the scope?

Comment: If the variable isn't used it will be garbage collected. If you remove the click handler `outerValue` could be cleaned up.

Comment: Is closures possible in a typed language?

Comment: The typing of a language has no effect on whether closures are possible. JavaScript is weakly typed but it might just as well be strongly typed.

Comment: Sorry, I meant compiled languages.